# Angular $q.all() not waiting for all promises

Tags: angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I have this code :

```
var promiseArr = [],
    innerPromises = [],
    innerIndex = 0;

angular.forEach(some_object, function (value, key) {
    console.log(1);
    innerPromises[innerIndex] = $q.defer();
    promiseArr.push(innerPromises[innerIndex].promise);
    (function(innerIndex) {
        func_returning_promise(args).then(function(data) {
            console.log(2);
            // Some code working on returned data
            innerPromises[innerIndex].resolve(true);
        });
    })(innerIndex);

    innerIndex++;
});

$q.all(promiseArr).then(function() {
    console.log(3);
});
```

`forEach` runs 3 times. The expected outcome would be

```
1
1
1
2
2
2
3
```

But `3` comes out before `2`s and after `1`s, and that seems completely illogical to me ! the `innerPromises` doesn't resolve but after `2`s has been logged.

Thanks ahead for any help.

Comment: Not part of my answer so I'll add as a comment: you don't have to create the inner promises explicitly. `func_returning_promise(args).then(...)` returns a promise, so you can just push that onto your promise array and it will be resolved or rejected automatically for you when the success function completes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that in extracting bits of code rather than posting a complete example you've changed the behaviour. Most likely in your original the `forEach()` is also inside an asynchronous callback which means the `$q.all()` is operating on an empty list and immediately resolves.

So the order I'm suggesting is:

1. You do something not shown which immediately resolves a promise A.
2. `$q.all()` operates on an empty list so the promise B it returns
      resolves.
3. Angular runs the success function for promise A which runs the
      `forEach` loop and prints all your `1` and appends promises into
      the array.
4. Then it runs the success function for promise B which prints the
      `3`.
5. Then the other promises complete and print `2`.

Answer (score 2):

your code seems incomplete, anyway after some adaptations I was able to make your code work on jsfiddle.
    https://jsfiddle.net/yw6qztxm/

```
angular.module('indexApp', []).controller('indexController', function($q,   $timeout) {

var promiseArr = [],
    innerPromises = [],
    innerIndex = 0;

var some_object = { 1:1, 2:2, 3:3 }
var args = false;

function func_returning_promise() {
  return $q(function(resolve) {
    $timeout(resolve, 100 + 100 * innerIndex);
  });
}

angular.forEach(some_object, function (value, key) {
    console.log(1);
    innerPromises[innerIndex] = $q.defer();
    promiseArr.push(innerPromises[innerIndex].promise);
    (function(innerIndex) {
        func_returning_promise(args).then(function(data) {
            console.log(2);
            // Some code working on returned data
            innerPromises[innerIndex].resolve(true);
        });
    })(innerIndex);

    innerIndex++;
});

$q.all(promiseArr).then(function() {
    console.log(3);
});

});
```

It does what is expected, in that 3 is logged for last, maybe you should make an working example with the missing functions and variables.